# Testing Library with Spring Properties

Tags: spring, junit5

my group has a few java / spring boot based REST services and a few java / springframework based shared libraries for them on an **intranet** project. i would like to create junit tests on one of our libraries that does some LDAP stuff for us. i don't want to mock in this case because i want to see if the LDAP methods we created actually work.

**without adding spring boot dependencies (because i don't want to add "functionality" to a project just for testing) how can i test, with junit5, our ldap library?**

*****UPDATED*****

i have something working now that is very close to what i pictured, having something like this in src/test/java area...

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyLdapLibTest {

  @Autowired
  private MyLdapLib myLib;

  @Tag("integrationTest")
  @Test
  public void test1() thorws Exception {
    String val = myLib.getSomething("my value");
    //assert here
  }


  @Configuration
  public static class SpringTestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    MyLdapLib createMyLib() {
      return new MyLdapLib();
    }

  }
```

with something like this in the build.gradle...

```
dependencies {

implementation 'com.unboundid:unboundid-ldapsdk'
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context'

testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'

}
```

the above dependencies won't start spring context when running junit tests (and my autowire is null.) keep in mind, we are just creating a libary jar file so i don't want any spring boot in the created jar. so the above dependencies would be preferable. where "regular" spring for building the library but spring boot for testing the library.

what does work is ...

```
dependencies {

implementation 'com.unboundid:unboundid-ldapsdk'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'

testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

}
```

that is very close to what i want but i feel like it is making me use a spring boot dependency in the implementation when i shouldn't have to (because in the first dependencies example the spring-context takes care of the @ValueS i have in my library classes and in my second, working dependencies example the actuator provides for the @ValueS in my the code)

**my new question then becomes... when running junit tests, why will spring context start up when actuator is set as implementation but won't start when actuator is set as testImplementation ???**

Comment: It looks like this project is already using Spring, what is your hesitation around adding the appropriate jars to test with?  If you add the Spring test dependencies, scope them as `test` and you won't be adding functionality, but you will be making your project a lot easier to work with.  Your code will be cleaner, your project will be easier to develop against, and you'll be following the testing strategies set forth by the creators of the framework you're using.  I wouldn't recommend anything else.

Comment: i guess because i was using spring (with full tomcat) before i used spring boot so i consider them (i.e. spring IOC and spring boot) as separate entities. my library should only need spring and not spring boot as well so i was trying to keep things (like the dependencies) to a minimum. bottom line, trying to be efficient with what is in my project. probably more of a theoretical thing of "what's the minimum" i need. i was thinking... before the days of spring boot, spring dependency injection had to be testable so why do i need spring boot annotations to test now.

Comment: revamped original question, hopefully clearer now?